# Paypal express sample code returning error 400 on PATCH

Tags: javascript, express, paypal, patch

I'm using the Paypal tutorial code to create a simple Paypal Express button, all seems to work until I add the onshippingchange code (which is again in their tutorial) - when it attempts to patch the order to add a shipping cost, Paypal returns error 400.

Code works if theres no attempt to patch the order, payment completes etc. Have contacted Paypal support but they are taking forever to respond and so far haven't been any use unfortunately

```
<script>
      const baseOrderAmount = '15.00';
const addFloats = (...floats) => floats.reduce((v, t) => parseFloat(t) + parseFloat(v), 0).toFixed(2);

  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
     onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // Capture the funds from the transaction
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // Show a success message to your buyer
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    }


onShippingChange: function(data, actions) {


        // Patch the shipping amount
        const shippingAmount =  '20.00';
        return actions.order.patch([
            {
                op: 'replace',
                path: '/purchase_units/@reference_id==default/amount',
                value: {
                    currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: addFloats(baseOrderAmount, shippingAmount),
                    breakdown: {
                        item_total: {
                            currency_code: 'USD',
                            value: baseOrderAmount
                        },
                        shipping: {
                            currency_code: 'USD',
                            value: shippingAmount
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
    }


  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I'd expect the Paypal order to be updated to 15.00 goods plus 20.00 shipping, however the paypal window returns a "something went wrong error" and the console shows an error 400

Comment: baseOrderAmount undefined?

Comment: baseOrderAmount is defined as a constant of 15 at the top of the script

Comment: Does the patch request that's being sent look correct in the network tab of your dev tools?  Is addFloats blowing up?  All the required fields set?

Comment: Do you get anything else back aside from the 400? I'd be really surprised if it doesn't have an error message of some sort.

Comment: PayPal support have advised that apparantly the issue is that I’m posting the patch command to the wrong url. However I can’t see where I’d state that the patch command had to be posted to a different url?

Answer (score 0):

The example code on the Paypal website currently appears to have a bug.

Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/shipping-callback/

Currently Paypal provides this code in their example:

```
path: '/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount'
```

Your code (It looks like you removed the quotes like I did at first):

```
path: '/purchase_units/@reference_id==default/amount',
```

However, this appears to be the correct code required:

```
path: "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount"
```